# no me salta el evento onclick

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-auth

estoy intentando hacer una insercion de un usuario y contraseña con firebase y javascript. Si elimino la funcion `eviar()` y cargo la pagina, me introduce el usuairo y contraseña correctamente. Pero si lo trato de hacer con la funcion `enviar()` la pagina no hace nada. Incluso he probado a poner un alert dentro del metodo `enviar()` pero no salta. En cambio si pongo el metodo `enviar()` en un script aparte del que contiene la configuracion de firebase, si que me salta sin problemas. ¿donde puede estar el error? Aqui os pongo el codigo completo de la pagina:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>Firebase</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="email" value="luilli.guillan@gmail.com" />
    <input type="text" id="pass" value="1234567"/>
    <button onclick="enviar()" >Enviar</button>

    <script type="module">

  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need

    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js';
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use

  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries


  // Your web app's Firebase configuration

  const firebaseConfig = {

    //my config

  };

 
  // Initialize Firebase

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth();
  
    function enviar(){
    var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
    alert("email="+email+" pass="+pass);

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });

  }
  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: creo que el <script type="module">  "module"  es el que te esta dando el problema no entiendo muy bien como se usa el module así que tendrás que investigarlo.

Comment: aquí un enlace que te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module

Comment: creo que solo tendrias que agregar esto-> window.enviar= function enviar() {
    ...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya probé la solución que te comente y creo que estoy en lo correcto

```
window.enviar= function enviar(){
var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
alert("email="+email+" pass="+pass);

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

}

al final así quedaría

Comment: perfecto. Esa es la solucion. Gracias.